# How to check and list all false conditionals in if statement - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm trying to improve my code and have better logging.

Is there an ideal way of how to tell which conditions are false in a list of conditionals?

i.e)

```
if(isAnimal && isCarnivore && isPlant){
 // does something
} else {
 // want to console.log all the false conditions in one console.log
}
```

We could write

```
let falseString = ""


if (!isAnimal) {
 falseString = falseString + "is not an Animal";
} 

if (!isCarnivore) {
 falseString = falseString + "is not a Carnivore";
}

if (!isPlant) {
 falseString = falseString + "is not a Plant";
}

console.log("string of false conditions" , falseString)
```

Then this would log a string of which conditions are false, but this seems to be a naive solution.

What is a better way to do this in JavaScript?

Thank you!

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place for more opinion-based questions. That said, you could just write `console.log(isAnimal)` and so on without having to write and concatenate a string for each possible condition and variable combination.

Comment: thank you. Yes that would be good, but in this case I need to have the results in one string and not in separate console logs

Comment: Can you elaborate on the purpose of the logging? Is it for debugging or for saving to log files to review later? The purpose greatly effects what could be considered better/more effective/etc. So in short: what is the improvement you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Philip the purpose is for debugging. So can track, which conditions are false, so we know which conditions are false and why the the code is going into the else case instead of the true branch

Comment: Then I would suggest having one globally defined object with all booleans. This way you can `console.log` them with one short statement and still see all at once in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate things by creating object of answers and then iterate it

```js
// Create object for answers
const answers = {};

// Alter object with answers...
answers.isAnimal = false;
answers.isCarnivore = false;
answers.isPlant = false;
answers.isHuman = true;
answers.isMineral = false;
answers.isInsect = false;

// Define result strings
let falseAnswers = "False answers is:";
let trueAnswers = "True answers is:";

// Loop answers
for(const answer in answers) {
  answers[answer] ? trueAnswers += ` ${answer}` : falseAnswers += ` ${answer}`;
}

// Log
console.log(trueAnswers);
console.log(falseAnswers);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are declared globally, you can store their names in an array and check whether it is `true` or not by referencing the `window` object:

```js
let falseString = ""

isAnimal = true
isCarnivore = false
isPlant = false

const booleans = ['isAnimal', 'isCarnivore', 'isPlant'];

const falseBooleans = booleans.filter(e => !window[e])

console.log(falseBooleans)
```

Comment: thanks, does window only work if it's associated with front end? I'm just writing these in the backend so it's not attached to any windows/browsers?

Comment: @Suzy Can you clarify what you mean by backend? Are you using NodeJS? If so, it should still work.

Comment: thanks, the filtering is a good idea.  I'm using webdriverIo and it says window is not defined?

Comment: @Suzy Try the code, the variables might be global by default.

Comment: yes I tried to run the code, but it still says in the cmd "window is not defined" I did npm install as well